# Copy files if directory does not exist on target

Tags: rsync, file-copy

Can you copy files (using rsync ideally but any scriptable tool considered) from server A to server B skipping directories that already exist on the target, and any files they contain?

```
Server A
FEED
--CUSTOMER1
----feed_12414.xml
--CUSTOMER2
----feed_6583.xml
--CUSTOMER3
----feed_97334.xml

Server B
FEED
--CUSTOMER1
----feed_new.xml
--CUSTOMER5
----feed_new.xml
```

Result should be:

```
Server B
FEED
--CUSTOMER1
----feed_new.xml
--CUSTOMER2
----feed_6583.xml
--CUSTOMER3
----feed_97334.xml
--CUSTOMER5
----feed_new.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync --ignore-existing --recursive /source_dir /destination_dir
```

is this what you mean ?